# SQL Server safely cast string and fail silently

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @input varchar(255) = 'abc'

select * from table where id = CAST(@input as int)
```

Can I do this so that the cast will fail silently, or default to some user-provided (or system default) value?

Comment: The initial assignment will fail. Did you mean to use another datatype?

Comment: haha yeah, thanks for the catch.  I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From SQL Server 2012 and up you can use [`try_convert`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28SQL.110%29.aspx) and [`try_parse`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126%28SQL.110%29.aspx) functions.

Until then you can use

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(11) = 'abc'

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id =  CAST(CASE WHEN @input NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN @input END AS INT)
```

You may need to tweak the test a bit (e.g. it disallows negative integers and allows positive ones bigger than the maximum int) but if you find a suitable test ([e.g. the one here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber)) and use a `CASE` statement you should avoid any casting errors as order of evaluation for `CASE` is [mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473045/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-not/7475067#7475067) guaranteed.

Comment: +1 Nice answer - the covers decimals as well (I was trying the ISNUMERIC function)

Comment: @Stormer - Your [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5757328) does not work. It would just check a string contains at least one number. Not *only* numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your select in `TRY-CATCH` block and re-issue the query in `CATCH` with default value.